# How do I design database for an application to deal with peculier needs of multiple countries

Tags: database-design, architecture

When developing a multi-regional application, what are the best practises for handling things like differences in currencies, working days and time differences when it comes to database design.

- Do you create a separate database for each different region/country?
- Have a database for the common tables that are not affected by country or regional peculiarity and then create separate databases for each peculiar region?
- Put them all in a single database and have relational parent-child references like say Countries table, then Currencies table, Charges table etc.

There is also the issue of Business day which varies for just about every country and every year. Say an agent will be charged penalties for each business day that they have not banked collections, since this is different for each country, How does one deal with this when designing the database.

I may have muddled my question up a bit but I hope the essence is clear enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you have other requirements that dictate otherwise (e.g. scalability/redundancy), the best way is to keep everything in a single DB instance, define a table that collects all the countries you are interested in (along with their country-specific properties).

E.g.:

```
Country-cd |Country-Name | Currency | Language | Time-zone | Region-cd
     it      Italy           EUR         IT        MET         EMEA
     ...     ...             ...         ...       ...         ...
     jp      Japan           JPY         jp        JST         Far-East
```

And then use the country code as part of the key for each other table that may have country-specific content... like prices:

```
 Item-id  | Country-cd  | Valid-from  | Valid-to    | Amount x unit
 950595   |    IT       | 03-MAY-2013 |  31-DEC-2099|    23.56 
 950595   |    JP       | 01-FEB-2013 |  12-AUG-2013|  2643.00
 950595   |    JP       | 13-AUG-2013 |  31-DEC-2099|  2810.00
```

So the same item is priced at 23.56 Euros in Italy, and it will instead sold for 2643 Yen in Jp, from Feb.1st to Aug.12th, and then will increase in price to 2810 Yen.

**Couple of caveats**

1. I have used ISO codes for country and the money. This should be
   robust enough to avoid problems in the future. FOR THE LOVE OF GOD
   DO NOT USE application-specific codes for things like states or
   currencies. Even if you are designing it for a small portion of the
   world, like, dunno... "German Speaking Countries" (Germany, Austria,
   part of Switzerland) resist the temptation to use things like
   GER/AUS/SWI or anything that is not standard.
2. Time zones are horribly hairy to manage. I put that in the same table as country just to illustrate what kind of data should be associated to the country entry, but in reality some countries span more than one time zone (ru, us) and therefore you probably need a more sophisticated schema.
3. On top of point (2) above, if your application really lives in a single-instance DB you have to decide a rule for how time is displayed to your users and *stick to it.* Consistently. See below.

The problem with world-spanning applications is that you may have a server in Bangalore with users in Rome. So you basically have two choices - you either timestamp every operation with the time zone of where the actual server "resides" and let the users adjust mentally for the discrepancies, or you still timestamp everything with a specific time zone (you can of course use UTC instead of local time, and this applies to the other method, too) and automagically translate this to the user local timezone while displaying.

So you may have something like "record created at UTC 12-MAY-2014 00:34" stored in your DB and show me "record was created at 12-MAY-2014 01:34 MET" because I am using your application from Italy.

(this will prove EASIER for the users especially if the application allows them to create entries with time as an input - for example booking a room for a meeting - but will cost you more in terms of development, and may become a bit complex to manage when the same record can be updated from different time zones).

These are the basics, really... you also have to read up about [I18N](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization), of course, and decide if you want error messages and UI labels to be multilingual. I18N cares mostly about that (i.e. how to manage input and output in different languages) but it also gives guidelines for more esoteric stuff like culturally-appropriated icons so I suggest to do a bit of research on it.

Comment: Good answer to an open-ended question